# Stencil Texture Paint - Paint bleeding

Tags: texture-painting

There is no better way to explain my problem than a screenshot, so here it is.

[image: blender screenshot]

Why is this happening and how do I deal with this?

Comment: are you sure that your unwrap is correct?

Comment: @moonboots i am pretty new to texturing. can you please elaborate?

Comment: You need to unwrap your object in order to paint on it, you can see the unwrapped object in the UV Editor window. If the unwrapped is bad, the result of the painting may be unexpected like here

Comment: @moonboots thanks a ton. that worked

Comment: do an Unwrap > Smart UV Project, it should work well